# The code is Working Fine.But displaying me only Last 5 Records using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

The code is Working Fine. But It's displaying me only Last 5 Records. It has more than 100 Records. I don't know what's happening. without using Ajax it's displaying me all records.

Actually, I am creating MLM Software. So it has 15 Levels. So I'm Displaying Records by Referal on each Level. So on 1st level with the same coding, all things are working fine. means displaying all records of 1st level. But on 2nd level just displaying me only last 5 records of 1st level referrals...So in 1st level, I have 17 users...

now I noticed that it's displaying only 1 users Refrels in the 2nd level.Not displaying others 16 users Referrals in 2nd Level.I'm New in Ajax.

So Please tell me where I'm Wrong. is it Loop Closing Problem? or any thing else. Please suggest me. Thanks..

1st Page - Fething Records From Database

```
<?php
    /* Database connection start */
    include_once ("db.php");
    // Inialize session
    session_start();
    /* Database connection end */
    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        print "
                    <script language='javascript'>
                        window.location = 'index.php';
                    </script>
                ";
    }

    // storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
    $requestData2= $_REQUEST;


    $columns22 = array( 
    // datatable column index  => database column name
        0 =>'Id', 
        1 => 'username',
        2=> 'fname'
    );

    //LEVEL 1 Fetching data
    // getting total number records without any search
    $totalref2 = 0;
    $totalrefear2 = 0;
    $frincome = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT Id,fname,email,doj,active,username,mobile,pcktaken,activeamt,activegreen";
    $sql.=" FROM newusers where referedby = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'";
    $query=mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("downline-grid-data2.php: get employees");
    $totalData2 = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    $totalFiltered22 = $totalData2;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $ac = "$row[active]";
        $countusername = "$row[username]";

    $sql22 = "SELECT Id,fname,email,doj,active,username,mobile,pcktaken,activeamt,activegreen";
    $sql22.=" FROM newusers where referedby = '$countusername'";

    if( !empty($requestData2['search']['value']) ) {   // if there is a search parameter, $requestData2['search']['value'] contains search parameter
        $sql22.=" AND ( Id LIKE '".$requestData2['search']['value']."%' ";    
        $sql22.=" OR username LIKE '".$requestData2['search']['value']."%' ";
            $sql22.=" OR fname LIKE '".$requestData2['search']['value']."%' )";
    }
    $query22=mysqli_query($con, $sql22) or die("downline-grid-data2.php: get employees");
    $totalFiltered22 = mysqli_num_rows($query22); // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result. 
    $sql22.=" ORDER BY ". $columns22[$requestData2['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData2['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData2['start']." ,".$requestData2['length']."   ";
    /* $requestData2['order'][0]['column'] contains colmun index, $requestData2['order'][0]['dir'] contains order such as asc/desc  */  
    $query22=mysqli_query($con, $sql22) or die("downline-grid-data2.php: get employees");
    $amountlimit = 0;
    $data2 = array();
    while( $row22=mysqli_fetch_array($query22) ) {  // preparing an array
        $nestedData=array(); 
    $ac2 = "$row22[active]";
    $countusername2 = "$row22[username]";
    $pcktook = "$row22[pcktaken]";
    $mobile = "$row22[mobile]";
    $activeamt2 = "$row22[activeamt]";
    $activegreen = "$row22[activegreen]";
    $doj2 = "$row[doj]";

    $qu = "SELECT level2 FROM  packages where id = $pcktook";
    $re = mysqli_query($con, $qu);
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($re)) {
    $ll2 = "$r[0]";
    }
    if ($ac2 == 1) {
    $status2 = "success";

        $totalrefear2 = $totalrefear2 + $activeamt1;
        $amountlimit = $amountlimit + 1;

    } else {
    $status2 = "danger";
    }
        $totalref2 = $totalref2 + 1;

        $nestedData[] = $countusername2;
        $nestedData[] = $doj2;
        $nestedData[] = $activeamt2;

        $data2[] = $nestedData;
        }
    }


    $json_data = array(
                "draw"            => intval( $requestData2['draw'] ),   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw. 
                "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData2 ),  // total number of records
                "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered22 ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
                "data"            => $data2   // total data array
                );

    echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format

    ?>
```

2nd page - Table and Ajax call by Table ID

```
    <table class="table-fill" id="tblstudentslevel2">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-left">Name</th>
                <th class="text-left">Date</th>
                <th class="text-left">Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="table-hover">     
        </tbody>
    </table> 
<script>
       /* $('#table1').DataTable({
            ordering: false,
            paging: true
        });
        */
        // Function added by USMAN, users-grid-data.php file is being used to fetch data from database. //
        $(document).ready(function() {
                var dataTable = $('#tblstudentslevel2').DataTable( {
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,

                    "ajax":{
                        url :"downline-grid-data2.php", // json datasource
                        type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                        error: function(){  // error handling
                            $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
                            $("#tblstudentslevel2").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
                            $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");

                        }
                    }
                } );
            } );
    </script>
```

Comment: Try narrow down the problem. E.g., can you get more than 5 rows from fake data with an AJAX call, so without actually getting it from a database?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I Edited My Post Please check.. in 1st level total 17 users and in 2nd level displaying me only 1 user Refrels, that are 5 users. can you please check the code? because in procedural PHP it's displaying me all users.

Answer (score 0):

There is something strange, you are using JQuery Datatable with an inner AJAX call. Serverside, you try to get Requested data, but I can't see where you are sending data... for example, how can you get $_REQUEST['start'] whereas there is any form data sent and any data in your AJAX call ?

Comment: I Edited, There is 2 pages, 1st - Fetching data from data base and on second page displaying data by Ajax

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at pageLength option and give it a try:

```
var dataTable = $('#tblstudentslevel2').DataTable( {
                "pageLength": 50,
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax":{
                    url :"downline-grid-data2.php", // json datasource
                    type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                    error: function(){  // error handling
                        $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
                        $("#tblstudentslevel2").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
                        $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");

                    }
                }
            } );`
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply
Nothing Happening. Same displaying only Last 5 Records.

Comment: Try removing the

    "draw"            => intval( $requestData2['draw'] ),

I think you have a problem there, maybe this parameter is sent by the plugin by default with the value 5

Comment: I tried but nothing happened, Actually, I am creating MLM Software. So it has 15 Levels. So i'm Displaying Records by Referal on each Level. So on 1st level with the same coding, all things are working fine. means displaying all records of 1st level. But on 2nd level just displaying me only last 5 records of 1st level referrals.

Answer (score 0):

LIKE THIS

```
$sql = "select * from tableName order by id DESC limit 5"
```